# How to get a 7.1 PCMle encode in an MOV container to stay a single track while also rendering as 8 mono tracks in an NLE like an MXF container

Tags: ffmpeg, editing, audio, file-formats, quicktime

I've been trying to convert Blu-Ray footage to the most efficient, yet least time consuming format for editing footage from them. For a while, I would make an MXF container and encode the h264 to DNxHD and the lossless compressed audio to pcm_s24le. I really liked how convenient it was to have my audio linked to my video, how it could be played as a single track in a media player, but then be inserted into my NLE as 6-8 separate mono tracks.

However, I found the DNxHD encodes to be unnecessary as they took up too much storage space and my NLE could perfectly handle the original h264 files in an MOV or MP4 container. But I noticed that switching from MXF to an MOV container meant that things that were jettisoned from the former were in the latter. Some of this was actually welcome, like the chapter markers, but I noticed that 7.1 audio (but not 5.1 for some reason) would now render in my NLE as a single 7.1 track.

I looked in MediaInfo and think I figured out that the issue is that the MOV container formats the channel layout while the MXF one doesn't. I'll paste the info to show what I mean

MOV FILE

> - ID : 2
> - Format : PCM
> - Format settings : Little / Signed
> - Codec ID : in24
> - Duration : 1 min 41 s
> - Bit rate mode : Constant
> - Bit rate : 9 216 kb/s
> - Channel(s) : 8 channels
> - Channel layout : L R C LFE Ls Rs Lb Rb
> - Sampling rate : 48.0 kHz
> - Bit depth : 24 bits
> - Stream size : 111 MiB (34%)
> - Title : English
> - Language : English
> - Default : Yes
> - Alternate group : 1
> - Menus : 3

MXF FILE

> - ID : 3
> - Format : PCM
> - Format settings : Little
> - Format settings, wrapping mode : Frame (AES)
> - Codec ID : 0D01030102060300
> - Duration : 1 min 13 s
> - Bit rate mode : Constant
> - Bit rate : 9 216 kb/s
> - Channel(s) : 8 channels
> - Sampling rate : 48.0 kHz
> - Frame rate : 23.976 FPS (2002 SPF)
> - Bit depth : 24 bits
> - Stream size : 81.1 MiB (5%)
> - Delay_SDTI : 0
> - Locked : Yes

Any ideas?

I tried this code:

```
ffmpeg -i "INPUT.mkv" -c:v copy -r 23.976 -c:a pcm_s24le -filter_complex "[0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c0[a0]; [0:a:1]pan=mono|c0=c0[a1]; [0:a:2]pan=mono|c0=c0[a2]; [0:a:3]pan=mono|c0=c0[a3]; [0:a:4]pan=mono|c0=c0[a4]; [0:a:5]pan=mono|c0=c0[a5]; [0:a:6]pan=mono|c0=c0[a6]; [0:a:7]pan=mono|c0=c0[a7]; [a0][a1][a2][a3][a4][a5][a6][a7]amerge=inputs=8" "OUTPUT.mov”
```

And got this error message:

```
Stream specifier ':a:4' in filtergraph description [0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c0[a0]; [0:a:1]pan=mono|c0=c0[a1]; [0:a:2]pan=mono|c0=c0[a2]; [0:a:3]pan=mono|c0=c0[a3]; [0:a:4]pan=mono|c0=c0[a4]; [0:a:5]pan=mono|c0=c0[a5]; [0:a:6]pan=mono|c0=c0[a6]; [0:a:7]pan=mono|c0=c0[a7]; [a0][a1][a2][a3][a4][a5][a6][a7]amerge=inputs=8 matches no streams.
```

Comment: This looks to be a behaviour of the NLE - there should be an option in it to a split each channel to a different track on the timeline.